# Какой файл запускает приложение NodeJs?

Tags: linux, node.js

Добрый день! Для того, чтобы запустить скрипт на `nodejs`, в консоли пишем `node script.js`. А какой файл запускает  приложение `NodeJs` в Linux?

Comment: Такой же. .....

Comment: `node.exe`? Я пишу в консоли `find / -name node.exe` - такого файла не находит

Comment: Это ж Linux, какой ещё `.exe` :) Там исполняемые бинарники расширений типично не имеют. Если у вас работает `node script.js`, то "где бинарник нода" можно узнать командой `which node`.

Comment: @D-side, благодарю! Какой-то путь выдало)  Я с `Linux` дел, вообще, не имел, вчерашнего дня)

Comment: А зачем вам этот путь, кстати?

Comment: @D-side, да, как оказалось - не зачем. Пишу (копирую с инета) для сервера файл `.conf` для `upstart`.  В примере есть строка `exec /usr/bin/nodejs`. Так не работает. Я думал это путь исполняемого файла. Проверил, а там его нет. Вот и искал. Пока искал понял, что это путь для команд. `Все сложно`.)

Answer (score 1):

Обычно на linux nodejs имеет имя процесса node и находится он тут

```
# /bin/node
```